# Blur event stops click event from working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It appears that the Blur event stops the click event handler from working? I have a combo box where the options only appear when the text field has focus. Choosing an option link should cause an event to occur.

I have a fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uXq5p/6/

To reproduce:

1. Select the text box
2. Links appear
3. Click a link
4. The blur even occurs and the links disappear
5. Nothing else happens.

Expected behavior:

On step 5, after blur occurs, the click even should also then fire. How do I make that happen?

**UPDATE:**

After playing with this for a while, it seems that someone has gone to great lengths to prevent an already-occurred click event from being handled if a blur event makes the clicked element Un-clickable.

For example:

```
$('#ShippingGroupListWrapper').css('left','-20px');
```

works just fine, but

```
$('#ShippingGroupListWrapper').css('left','-2000px');
```

prevents the click event.

This appears to be a bug in Firefox, since making an element un-clickable should prevent ***future*** clicks, but ***not*** cancel ones that have already occurred when it could be clicked.

Other things that prevent the click event from processing:

```
$('#ShippingGroupListWrapper').css('z-index','-20');
$('#ShippingGroupListWrapper').css('display','none');
$('#ShippingGroupListWrapper').css('visibility','hidden');
$('#ShippingGroupListWrapper').css('opacity','.5');
```

I've found a few other questions on this site that are having similar problems. There seem to be two solutions floating around:

1. Use a delay. This is bad because it creates a race condition between the hiding and the click event handler. Its also sloppy.
2. Use the `mousedown` event. But this isn't a great solution either since `click` **is** the correct event for a link. The behavior of `mousedown` is counter-intuitive from a UX perspective, particularly since you can't cancel the click by moving the mouse off the element before releasing the button.

I can think of a few more.

3.Use `mouseover` and `mouseout` on the ***link*** to enable/disable the blur event for the field. This doesn't work with keyboard tabing since the mouse is not involved.

4.The best solution would be something like:

```
$('#ShippingGroup').blur(function()
{
   if($(document.activeElement) == $('.ShippingGroupLinkList'))
      return; // The element that now has focus is a link, do nothing
   $('#ShippingGroupListWrapper').css('display','none'); // hide it.
}
```

Unfortunately, `$(document.activeElement)` seems to always return the body element, not the one that was clicked. But maybe if there was a reliable way to know either 1. which element now has focus or two, which element caused the blur (not which element is blurring) from within the blur handler. Also, is there any other event (besides `mousedown`) that fires before blur?

Comment: The problem is the blur event is firing before the click. Since the blur hides those elements, you end up clicking nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure the hiding is the problem. I tried setting the opacity to 50% instead of hiding them and the click event still does not occur. Please see jsfiddle.net/75sgt/1

Comment: After further experimentation, it's the new un-clicability thats retroactively "un-clicking" an already clicked element. See my update above.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`click` event triggers after the `blur` so the link gets hidden. Instead of `click` use `mousedown` it will work.

```
$('.ShippingGroupLinkList').live("mousedown", function(e) {
    alert('You wont see me if your cursor was in the text box');
});
```

Other alternative is to have some delay before you hide the links on `blur` event. Its upto you which approach to go for.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uXq5p/9/)**

Comment: using a delay is dangerous. Should stick with mousedown.

Comment: Yes, even I would always go with `mousedown` instead of having a dirty delay logic.

Comment: Delay is bad because... it creates a race condition? So the problem isn't that the click even won't fire after blur, but that the click event won't fire on an element that is "display:none"? What if instead of display:none, the links were hidden with opacity:0 or similar?

Comment: I tried (http://jsfiddle.net/75sgt/1/) with 50% opacity and it does not work. I don't think the problem is that the element is invisible, it just isn't executing the click event after the blur.

Comment: @Nick - I see, `blur` event triggers then it shows an alert then focus is moved to alert box before even `click` event is fired. I think go with `mousedown` approach it is the best fit to achieve your requirement.

Comment: If I use console.log() instead of alert(), the body element is what gets the focus.

Comment: also to note: this will fire on RIGHT click too, which click does not usually trigger. your handler should include `if (e.which === 1) { }`

Comment: Be careful. Are you sure this will work for users who aren't using a mouse to activate links or focus/blur an element?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli please see my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896084/jquery-ajax-on-focusout-on-submit-requires-2-clicks

Comment: Isn't mousedown bad for accessibility?

Answer (score 5):

You could try the `mousedown` event instead of `click`.

```
$('.ShippingGroupLinkList').live("mousedown", function(e) {
    alert('You wont see me if your cursor was in the text box');
});
```

This is clearly not the best solution as a `mousedown` event is not achieved the same way for the user than a `click` event. Unfortunately, the `blur` event will cancel out `mouseup` events as well.

Comment: I believe a mousedown triggers a blur. An alternative would be to prevent the propagation on mousedown and perform your action on mouseup.

Answer (score 4):

Performing an action that should happen on a `click` on a `mousedown` is bad UX. Instead, what's a `click` effectively made up of? A `mousedown` and a `mouseup`.

Therefore, stop the propagation of the `mousedown` event in the `mousedown` handler, and perform the action in the `mouseup` handler.

An example in ReactJS:

```
<a onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()}
   onMouseUp={() => alert("CLICK")}>
   Click me!
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

> 4.The best solution would be something like:
>
> ```
> $('#ShippingGroup').blur(function()
> {
>    if($(document.activeElement) == $('.ShippingGroupLinkList'))
>       return; // The element that now has focus is a link, do nothing
>    $('#ShippingGroupListWrapper').css('display','none'); // hide it.
> }
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, $(document.activeElement) seems to always return the
>   body element, not the one that was clicked. But maybe if there was a
>   reliable way to know either 1. which element now has focus or two,
>   which element caused the blur (not which element is blurring) from
>   within the blur handler.

What you may be looking for is [e.relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget). So when clicking the link, `e.relatedTarget` should get populated with the link element, so in your blur handler, you can choose not to hide the container if the element clicked is within the container (or compare it directly with the link):

```
$('#ShippingGroup').blur(function(e)
{
   if(!e.relatedTarget || !e.currentTarget.contains(e.relatedTarget)) {
   // Alt: (!e.relatedTarget || $(e.relatedTarget) == $('.ShippingGroupLinkList'))

       $('#ShippingGroupListWrapper').css('display','none'); // hide it.
   }
}
```

(`relatedTarget` may not be supported in older browsers for `blur` events, but it appears to work in latest Chrome, Firefox, and Safari)

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately this doesn't work: `relatedTarget` is set only if the newly focused element is a "focusable" element, such as a link or an `input`/`select`/etc. It doesn't get set if you click on some `div`/etc..

Answer (score 1):

If `this.menuTarget.classList.add("hidden")` is the blur behavior that hides the clickable menu, then I succeeded by waiting 100ms before invoking it.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.menuTarget.classList.add()
}, 100)
```

This allowed the click event to be processed upon the `menuTarget` DOM before it was hidden.

Comment: delaying worked for me too. since I was using routerLink, not onclick...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a later reply, but I had this same issue, and a lot of these solutions didn't really work in my scenario. `mousedown` is not functional with forms, it can cause the enter key functionality to change on the submit button. Instead, you can set a variable `_mouseclick` true in the `mousedown`, check it in the `blur`, and `preventDefault()` if it's true. Then, in the `mouseup` set the variable false. I did not see issues with this, unless someone can think of any.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue while using jQuery blur, click handlers where I had an input name field and a Save button. Used blur event to populate name into a title placeholder. But when we click save immediately after typing the name, only the blur event gets fired and the save btn click event is disregarded.

The hack I used was to tap into the event object we get from blur event and check for event.relatedTarget.

PFB the code that worked for me:

```
$("#inputName").blur(function (event) {
        title = event.target.value;
        //since blur stops an immediate click event from firing - Firing click event here
        if (event.relatedTarget ? event.relatedTarget.id == "btnSave" : false) {
            saveBtn();
        }
    });

$("#btnSave").click(SaveBtn)
```

As already discussed in this thread - this is due to blur event blocking click event when fired simultaneously. So I have a click event registered for Save Btn calling a function which is also called when blur event's related Target is the Save button to compensate for the click event not firing.
Note: Didnt notice this issue while using native onclick and onblur handlers - tested in html.

Answer (score 0):

late to the party, but if there is a specific element being clicked, you can use e.relatedTarget to identify it, then manually call the function that should occur on click

```
onBlur (e) {
  // your on blur code
  if (e.relatedTarget.className.includes('button-class')) this.buttonAction()
},
```