# jQuery: fire click() before blur() event

Tags: jquery, click, onblur

I have an input field, where I try to make autocomplete suggestion. Code looks like

```
<input type="text" id="myinput">
<div id="myresults"></div>
```

On input's `blur()` event I want to hide results' div:

```
$("#myinput").live('blur',function(){
     $("#myresults").hide();
});
```

When I write something into my input I send request to server and get json response, parse it into ul->li structure and put this ul to my `#myresults` div.

When I click to this parsed li element I want to set value from li to input and hide `#myresults` div

```
$("#myresults ul li").live('click',function(){
     $("#myinput").val($(this).html());
     $("#myresults").hide();
});
```

Everything is going good, but when I click to my li `blur()` event fires before `click()` and input's value don't get li's html.

How can I set up `click()` event before `blur()`?

Comment: so that case why you use blur function ? when your need is already fullfilled from click function.

Comment: This probably won't change the order that your events are firing, but if `blur` is really firing after you click on an `li`, then you probably don't need to execute `$("#myresults").hide()` in the click handler. What it seems like is happening is that `$(this).html()` is returning an empty string. Could you `log` or `alert` `$(this).html()` to make sure?

Comment: @OwaisIqbal sometimes there's no results, sometimes user don't want to select anything from suggestions, sometimes user don't want to use this input anymore, but I must hide unused result

Comment: @veeTrain there're many actions in my handlers, I've just minimized them to easy understanding the problem in my question. p.s. I've tried to add watch-point in firebug on `blur()` and `click()` handlers, there's no actions after `blur()` ends

Comment: It looks like you need to queue the functions. Try taking a look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me. The First-In-First-Out (FIFO) portion may pertain to you

Comment: I'm not sure what might be happening since you have more event handlers than what you're showing. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8v4Q/) doing what it looks like you are wanting; does it approximate the behavior you're trying to create? I'm calling `show()` on blur to give something to click on. Can you create the problem there?

Answer (score 331, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Listen to `mousedown` instead of `click`.

The `mousedown` and `blur` events occur one after another when you press the mouse button, but `click` only occurs when you release it.

#### Solution 2

You can `preventDefault()` in `mousedown` to block the dropdown from stealing focus. The slight advantage is that the value will be selected when the mouse button is released, which is how native select components work. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yyv4rd7/)

```js
$('input').on('focus', function() {
    $('ul').show();
}).on('blur', function() {
    $('ul').hide();
});

$('ul').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}).on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('input').val(this.textContent).blur();
});
```

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me in this same situation! Easy change! Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you :) But can you explain why listening to mousedown instead of click works like charm ?

Comment: @MudassirAli because mousedown event comes before blur, and click comes after. http://jsfiddle.net/f3BKP/

Comment: Solution #1 is in my opinion the better choice. Simple and effective. Timeout would mean more to code + more room for unexpected behavior (how long a time out? long enough to register the click, but not too long to confuse the use...).

Comment: @cw24 You're right, timeout would be too unreliable. I've updated the answer with a better alternative solution.

Comment: Solution #2 is ingenious. I would have never figured it out! Thanks

Comment: I got stumped translating this solution to angular's attribute based events but I found that if I preventDefault on mousedown on the same element that was failing to be clicked due to a blur event somewhere else, it works. Like this: `<li (click)="handler()" (mousedown)="$event.preventDefault()"></li>`

Comment: I had a similar issue on a react app and the second option worked just fine, thank you so much! –

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('blur', "#myinput", hideResult);

$(document).on('mousedown', "#myresults ul li", function(){
     $(document).off('blur', "#myinput", hideResult); //unbind the handler before updating value
     $("#myinput").val($(this).html()).blur(); //make sure it does not have focus anymore
     hideResult(); 
     $(document).on('blur', "#myinput", hideResult);  //rebind the handler if needed
});

function hideResult() {
     $("#myresults").hide();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yjFAV/8/)

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue and using `mousedown` is not an option for me.

I solved this by using `setTimeout` in the handler function

```
        elem1.on('blur',function(e) {

            var obj = $(this);

            // Delay to allow click to execute
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (e.type == 'blur') {

                  // Do stuff here

                }
            }, 250);
        });

        elem2.click( function() {
            console.log('Clicked');
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I just answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46676463/227578

An alternative to the mousedown solutions is have it ignore blur events caused by clicking specific elements (i.e., in your blur handler, skip the execution if it's a result of clicking a specific element).

```
$("#myinput").live('blur',function(e){
     if (!e.relatedTarget || !$(e.relatedTarget).is("#myresults ul li")) {
         $("#myresults").hide();
     }
});
```

Comment: in my case, event.relatedTarget returns null, any idea why could that be ?

Comment: ok, got the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764494/blur-event-relatedtarget-returns-null

Answer (score 0):

Mousedown solutions does not work for me, when I click on non button elements. So here is what I've done with blur function in my code:

```
.on("blur",":text,:checkbox,:radio,select",function() {
/*
* el.container 
* container, you want detect click function on.
*/
            var outerDir = el.container.find(':hover').last();
            if (outerDir.length) {
                if ($.inArray(outerDir.prop('tagName'), ["A","SELECT"] ) != -1 || outerDir.prop('type') == 'button' || outerDir.prop('type') == 'submit') {
                    outerDir.click();
                }
                if (outerDir.prop('type') == 'checkbox') {
                    outerDir.change();
                }
                return false;
            }
/*          
* YOUR_BLUR_FUNCTION_HERE;
*/
});
```