# Prevent other event handlers, from first handler, in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have input field and submit button on page.

```
<form id="searchform">
<input id="s" type="search" autocomplete="off" name="s" value="">
<div id="search-submit" class="input-group-addon">
    <i>SUBMIT</i>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is jQuery code:

```
var inProgress = false; 

$("#search-submit").on("click", function() {
    inProgress = true;
    alert ("Form Submit");
    inProgress = false;   
});

$("#s").blur(function () {
    if ( ! inProgress ) {
        alert ("Blur");
    inProgress = false; 
    }
});
```

I would like to prevent blur if clicked from input field to Submit div, but want to allow it if clicked from input field to some other part of page. I can't use button for submit.

I have put up the fiddle [jsfiddle.net/405kzboh/1](http://jsfiddle.net/405kzboh/1)

But now I even don't understand why Click event is not triggered before the Blur event if someone click from input to Submit!

Comment: Blur event happens first, then click.

Answer (score 3):

The mousedown event on the target element will be called before the blur event on the textbox so you can hook into that event to set your in progress flag.

```
var inProgress = false; 

$("#search-submit").on("mousedown", function() {
    inProgress = true;
});

$("#search-submit").on("click", function() {
    console.log ("Form Submit");
    inProgress = false;   
});

$("#s").on("blur", function () {
    if ( ! inProgress ) {
        console.log ("Blur");
    }
});
```

I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/405kzboh/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the events' timeStamps and use it as a condition in the if statement within the `blur` event handler. And you would have to delay the if statement somewhat so the click event can register.
var inProgress = false; 
    //Initialize
    var oEvent = {click:0,blur:0};

```
$("#search-submit").on("click", function(e) {
    //capture click timestamp
    oEvent[e.type] = e.timeStamp; 
    inProgress = true; 
    alert ("Form Submit");
    inProgress = false; 
});

$("#s").on("blur", function (e) {
    //capture blur timestamp
    oEvent[e.type] = e.timeStamp; 

    //delay this code so click can register
    setTimeout(function() { 

        //check if click happened after blur
        if ( ! inProgress && oEvent.click < oEvent.blur ) { 
            alert ("Blur");
            inProgress = false; 
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/405kzboh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652852/jquery-fire-click-before-blur-event

Solution 1: stop event propogation in mousedown event, if you want to go with the click event

$("#search-submit").on("click", function() {      
    inProgress = true
    alert ("Form Submit");
    inProgress = false;      
});

$("#s").on("blur", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ( ! inProgress ) {
        alert ("Blur");
        inProgress = false; 
    }
});

$("#search-submit").on("mousedown", function(event) {  
    event.preventDefault();
});


Solution:2 -> use mousedown instead of click event

$("#search-submit").on("mousedown", function(event) {      
    inProgress = true;
    alert ("Form Submit");
    inProgress = false;  
    $("#s").off("blur");
});

$("#s").on("blur", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ( ! inProgress ) {
        alert ("Blur");
        inProgress = false; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that Blur event fires before Click, so I need to use onMousedown event to catch the click on Div.

All the answers here are good, but more complicated than it should be, so I come out with my own solution:

```
$("#search-submit").on("mousedown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log ("Form Submit");
});

$("#s").on("blur", function () {
    console.log ("Blur"); 
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dampas/405kzboh/4/)