# Angular2 roll-my-own dropdown hide if clicking away?

Tags: angular

I have a `div` that I want to show/hide on focus/blur of an `input`. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying:

```
<input (focus)="ShowDropDown=true;" (blur)="ShowDropDown=false;" />
<div *ngIf="ShowDropDown">
  <ul>
    <li (click)="...">...</li>
    <li (click)="...">...</li>
    <li (click)="...">...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This `div` contains a list of elements to click on. My problem is that the `input`'s blur is happening before the `li`'s click.

I want to keep things simple. I don't want to set everything's focus or click event to set `ShowDropDown=false` but I need to keep the dropdown div open for interaction.

I could have `ShowDropDown` be a number where focusing adds 1 to it, mousing over the div adds another 1 to it, blurring the input subtracts 1, and mousing out of the div subtracts 1 but I imagine that could go out of sync really easily.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Can I force blur to run after click?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652852/jquery-fire-click-before-blur-event): mousedown will happen before blur but click will happen after. I simply change to

```
<input (focus)="ShowDropDown=true;" (blur)="ShowDropDown=false;" />
<div *ngIf="ShowDropDown">
  <ul>
    <li (mousedown)="...">...</li>
    <li (mousedown)="...">...</li>
    <li (mousedown)="...">...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This gives me the order of events I want without doing delays or "reference counting" where the mouse is or adding a click event to everything else in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

A better way to listen to global events is

```ts
@Comonent({...
  host: {'(window:click)': 'clickHandler()'}
})
```

**Original**

Just check if the click was inside or outside your dropdown:

```ts
import {DOM} from angular2/platform/common_dom;

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  DOM.getGlobalEventTarget('window')
     .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
       // check if event.target is a child of elementRef.nativeElement
       // if not hide the dialog
     });
}
```

I cant currently make this work in TS though `DOM` is always undefined.
This works fine in Dart.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1LImWdksAoHEuJE8CKFT?p=preview)

I created an issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6904

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a simple hack like this

```
 <input (focus)="ShowDropDown=true;" (blur)="ShowDropDown=false;" />
 <div *ngIf="ShowDropDown">
   <ul>
     <li (click)="...; ShowDropDown = true">...</li>
     <li (click)="...; ShowDropDown = true">...</li>
     <li (click)="...; ShowDropDown = true">...</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Not the most elegant solution, but should work

Comment: My click events in the li elements aren't running at all or I wouldn't need a work around. The blur happens first, sets ShowDropDown to false, the div is hidden, the click registers on the element behind the div.