# Display:none is preventing click event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search box with search suggestion:

```
<input id="searchBar" />
<div id="searchSuggestion"></div>
```

The div `searchSuggestion` is automatically updated via jQuery ajax when an input is made (code not shown). To hide / show the autocomplete suggestions (which appear below the search textbox), I use:

```
$searchBar.blur(function () {
    $searchSuggestion.css("display", "none");
});
$searchBar.focus(function () {
    $searchSuggestion.css("display", "");
});
```

So far so good.

Now, I want to auto-fill the textbox when a user clicks on a search suggestion item:

```
$searchSuggestion.on("click", ".item", function () {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

The problem is, clicking the search suggestion item causes the textbox to lose focus, therefore `display:none` is set on the search suggestion items, which causes the `click` event to not fire!

If I remove the `display:none` code, everything works fine.

How can I work around this conflict?

Comment: you've pretty much laid out the logic you need. when you click on *anything but* the searchSuggestion, hide the search suggestions.

Comment: Delegate the click. If event.target is not suggestion or searchbar, hide

Comment: @KevinB exactly how to do that? Capture the global mouse-click event?

Comment: ...and I don't understand the down-votes. Not at all.

Comment: @kevin that is one way, yes.

Comment: @KevinB wouldn't that lead to performance issues though? If the page has a lot of elements.

Comment: @kevin the number of elements doesn't affect how many times the event would be bound/called

Comment: @KevinB I mean if this strategy is repeatedly used for many elements in the page.

Comment: @kevin you should be able to do all of that with a single click event, but, yes, having 50 click events on the same element could be a performance problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652852/jquery-fire-click-before-blur-event) solution, which prevents the mousedown event from propagating and causing the element to lose focus before click (which requires mouseup) is fired:

```
$searchSuggestion.on("mousedown", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).on("click", ".item", function () {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround this by adding a small `timeout` in your `blur` handler, try this for example:

```
$searchBar.blur(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $searchSuggestion.css("display", "none");
    }, 150);
});
```

Comment: isnt' this missing the whole.... clearTimeout when clicking on a suggestion item portion?

Comment: Is it possible to do this without timeout? Ideally, the moment when the user clicks the suggestion, the focus is already known. I just need the click() event to fire before the blur() event.

Comment: @KevinB No need to clear `timeout`s since it creates only one instance, intervals on the other hand needs to be cleared

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni Right, but... if you don't clear it, then it's going to hide shortly after clicking a suggestion item... I guess that works if it's what you want

Comment: @kevin the `blur` handler is not aware of `click` event, and cannot know which item was clicked!

Comment: @KevinB yes that was the intention, click then hide as required in the question.