# How to disable jQuery blur event on certain selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery and HTML which hide the search result when the focus on the input has been lost.

This code hides my div with id `#searchResult` when the elements on `#searchResult` are clicked. I want to **disable blur** when elements on `#searchResult` div are clicked. Basically, I want to hide `<div id="searchResult">` when the focus is lost and show when it's on focus. How can I achieve that?

```js
$(document).on("blur", "#txtSearchTerm", function () {
    $('#searchResult').hide();
});

$(document).on("focus", "#txtSearchTerm", function () {
    $('#searchResult').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtSearchTerm" type="text">

<div id="searchResult">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
                <div class="title">Google.com</div>
                <div class="content">Click here</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
               <div class="title">Google.com</div>
               <div class="content">Click here</div>
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**`<div id="searchResult">`  will be hidden on every click of elements inside it.**

Comment: Maybe check the [Jquery not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: I am confused how to use not on blur event. how can disable blur when clicked on `<div id="searchResult">`'s child

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: fire click() before blur() event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652852/jquery-fire-click-before-blur-event)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need `blur` event to achieve that:

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("div") && $(e.target).has("ul > li")){
        $('#searchResult').show()
    }
    else $('#searchResult').hide()
    
    if ($(e.target).is(':focus')){
        $('#searchResult').show()
    }
})
```

```css
#searchResult{
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtSearchTerm" type="text">
Click out the input to hide div
<div id="searchResult">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
                <div class="title">Google.com</div>
                <div class="content">click here</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
               <div class="title">Google.com</div>
               <div class="content">click here</div>
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: once the link is clicked `<div id="searchResult">` didn't hide.

Comment: even in mouse down

Comment: @KiranShahi Updated answer. Do you want to hide #searchResult when clicked out that element?

Comment: yes @SilverSurfer I want to hide again when the elements on `<div id="searchResult">` is clicked.

Comment: Everything is going under dom, ajax request, hide/show etc.

Comment: @KiranShahi Hey bro check my updated answer, I finally made as you need

Comment: Thank you bro, I will implement it on Monday. Its weekend here :D

Comment: No problem I will,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156681/discussion-between-kiran-shahi-and-silversurfer).

Answer (score 6):

You can simply turn off your blur event with the following code.

```
$(document).off("blur", "#txtSearchTerm");
```

Comment: I don't want to off blur, I want to off blur on `<div id="searchResult">`'s child click only

Comment: elements on `<div id="searchResult">` are link, so e.preventDefault();  will not work.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that, because the blur is fired before the click on the child.
So you would need to add an event handler on the document which closes the results. You cancel that event when someone clicks the results. Something like this:

```js
$('#txtSearchTerm').click(function(e) {
  $('#searchResult').show();
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    $('#searchResult').hide();
});

$('#searchResult').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtSearchTerm" type="text">

<div id="searchResult">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
                <div class="title">Google.com</div>
                <div class="content">Click here</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
               <div class="title">Google.com</div>
               <div class="content">Click here</div>
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

My advise it to check relatedTarget and kill blur only if user clicks on certain elements.

```js
$(document).on("blur", "#txtSearchTerm", function (e) {
  if ($(e.relatedTarget).hasClass("no-blur")){
  }else{
  $('#searchResult').hide();    
  }

});
$(document).on("focus", "#txtSearchTerm", function () {
    $('#searchResult').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtSearchTerm" type="text">

<div id="searchResult">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
                <div class="title">Google.com</div>
                <div class="content">click here</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
               <div class="title">Google.com</div>
               <div class="content">click here</div>
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```