# HTML how to keep focuing state of input after clicking another element(eg button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to keep focuing state after click a button. Keeping state means:

- If `<input/>` is focused, keep focus after clicking the button;
- **If `<input/>` is not focused before, don't focus it after clicking the button**.

So, after clicking, as current focusing state of the `<input/>` is always 'not focus', I want to get the previous focusing state of the `<input/>`.

The problem is that `blur` is always called before `click` event.

What I have tried:

```
// onclick event
this.$iptPassword.on('click', this.toggleShowPassword);
```

```
// callback
toggleShowPassword() {
    console.log(this.$iptPassword.is(':focus')); // always return false
    this.$iptPassword.attr('type', this.$iptPassword.attr('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password');
}
```

Comment: `Element.focus()`

Comment: 1. There is no <click> HTML element, maybe you want to use `.click .img-eye` instead?
2. please provide the full HTML on a working snippet
3. add `jquery` tag
4. `console.log($iptPassword);` have desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a working Plnkr - [Toggle input type + Focus state](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Iv0pINlk0YW4AtM7?preview)

Introduced 2 variables - 
"inputWasFocused" & "clickWasOutsideOfScope" - using those variables, I'm able save the last input state (focused / not focused) - before the actual "blur" event

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here. But things are more complex in a touch screen.

[jQuery: fire click() before blur() event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652852/jquery-fire-click-before-blur-event)