# Not calling click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have kind of strange problem.

I'm trying to add a couple of events to som DOM elements (all existing, some initially hidden:

```
$self.on("focus", function () {
    $self.next().css("display", "inline-block");
});

$self.on("blur", function () {
    $(this).next().hide();
});

$self.parent().find(".icon-ok").on("click", function() {
    console.log("icon.ok")
});
```

You can see the relevant part of the DOM here (self is the span user-name):
[image]

Later on, the element eventually because visible and I can click on it. However, the event handler is never called. If I remove the blur event, than the click event works. However, I need both.

What's going on here?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Try `$self.closest(".user-name").on("click", ".icon-ok", function() {
    console.log("icon.ok")
});`

Comment: Properly (and just a guess) that one of these events requires a `return true;` to continue onto other event types.

Comment: falsarella, Mathew, neither worked :(

Comment: What element is `$self`?

Comment: $self is <span id="user_fullname"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335325/blur-event-stops-click-event-from-working) the blur cancels out the click (due to event order) but using mousedown instead of blur may help you get both.

**UPDATE**: Added code based on comment

```
$self.parent().find(".icon-ok").on("mousedown", function() {
  console.log("icon.ok") 
});
```

Comment: Maybe I mis-understand your question, but use it instead of the click.  $self.parent().find(".icon-ok").on("mousedown", function() {
    console.log("icon.ok")
});    Your "click" will then trigger before your blur.

Comment: Ah, mousedown instead of click worked! Simple and great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be the classic delegation problem, where in the element is not available in the DOM when the event is bound.

Delegate the event and see if that solves your problem.

```
$self.on("click", ".icon-ok", function() {
    console.log("icon.ok")
});
```

User `$self` if that element is visible or any closest ancestor that you can find which is always present in the DOM.

Comment: .icon-ok" actually is in the DOM when the event is set up, that's not the problem. I tried your suggestion just in case and it does not work.