# Why does a click event not reach the <body>?

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

This [slider](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjzOmW) is runnning in an animation loop unless one of the dots at the top is clicked. Then, the animated elements (the `<span>` dots and the `<figure>`s) get a style that stop the animation.

```
<section id="slider">
    <span class="control" tabindex="1"></span>
    <span class="control" tabindex="2"></span>
    <span class="control" tabindex="3"></span>
    <figure class="slide">
        <!--Image 1--->
    </figure>
    <figure class="slide">
        <!--Image 2--->
    </figure>
    <figure class="slide">
        <!--Image 3--->
  </section>
```

Script:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var slider = document.querySelector('#slider');
    var animated = slider.querySelectorAll('.control, .slide');

    function switchAll (focus) {
        animated.forEach(function (el) {
            el.style['animation-name'] = focus ? 'none' : null;
        });
    }

    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        switchAll(slider.querySelector('.control:focus'));
    });
};
```

After the animation is stopped, it should restart if something other than the dots is clicked (so that they loose focus). But **on Firefox** this works only if the click is outside of the `#slider`.

Clicking inside the currently shown `<figure>` lets it disappear - this is expected CSS behavior, since no dot has the focus. But the animation does not restart; the first `click` event does not reach the `<body>`. Only a second click triggers the event listener.

I've also tried to attach the event to the `#slider`, but the result is the same. It seems as if the event would not bubble past the `<figure>` elements, attaching it on those works, but is obviously a inferior solution.

Anyway I'd like to understand what happens to the event.

Comment: The event itself _does_ reach the `body` (you can confirm it by adding `console.log(e)` to the click handler), but `'.control:focus'` selects nothing because setting `tabindex` without value seems not enough to make non-interactive elements like `span`s focusable. With `tabindex=-1`, they become focusable and the click changes their behavior (also animation looks a bit strange after this change).

Comment: It seems the the tabindex number is needed for Chrome, on Firefox it can be left off. The problem I describe seems to be FF-specific. - What you call " a bit strange" is expected bevavior btw.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I fell into this trap: [Blur event stops click event from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335325)

The moment the control looses focus, the slide is moved outside the visible area, and the click isn't hitting it. But it does not hit the background either; it really seems the click is actively canceled.

The solution is to couple the runing of the animation not with the click event, but with the focus/blur events.