# Jquery on click doesn't fire when blur is also bound

Tags: javascript, jquery

My blur event fires but not my click event. If I remove the blur event code the click event works fine.

How do I change the order these events fire?

```
$.fn.autoComplete = function () {

    $(document).on('click', '#' + settings.resultsDivId + ' tr', function () {
            console.log('click fired');
            $('#' + settings.resultsDivId).hide();
    });

    this.on('blur', function () {
        console.log('blur fired');
        $('#' + settings.resultsDivId).hide();
    });

    function AutoComplete(term) {
        // ajax call stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: you have a `}` in your click event. Remove that

Comment: Typo. Voting to close.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's a typo in the question not in the code. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3953989 since its not working still, please post all relevant code, aka html

Comment: If you remove the blur event then it works fine? Maybe the event fires so it hides the element with id set in `settings.resultsDivId` which make it impossible to click on?

Comment: Include enough code for us to reproduce your error (HTML, CSS).

Comment: @AlonEitan Correct. I believe this is exactly what's happening but not sure how to solve it

Comment: @user3953989 For that we'll have to see your html structure, as Scott mentioned in his comment

Comment: @user3953989 Please also include example of how you use your code and explain what exactly are you trying to achieve, so you can get better answers to this question. There's a high chance for a solution, provided we have all the necessary details

Comment: changing `click` to `mousedown` solved it. Apparently `click` fires after `blur` and this was why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `click` to `mousedown` solved it. Apparently `click` fires after `blur`.

[Blur event stops click event from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335325/blur-event-stops-click-event-from-working)

Comment: I was just about to post a solution, but if this works then great. My solution was to remove the blur event and instead check if the user clicked on the table or outside it and based on that to hide the table