# Why is the first click not firing?

Tags: javascript

The first click isn't firing and I can't work out why.

All subsequent clicks work fine. If I reload the page, same problem: first click: nothing happens.

I've tried accessing other html elements as test in the `queryselector` but it doesn't make a difference.

Here's the code (I'm trying to do this in vanilla JS):

```
const cities = [];
fetch(endpoint)
  .then(blob => blob.json())
  .then(data =>cities.push(...data));

function findMatches(wordToMatch, cities) {
  return cities.filter(place => {
    const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi'); 
    return place.city.match(regex) || place.state.match(regex) 
  });
}

function displayMatches() {
  const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, cities);

  const html = matchArray.map(place => {
  const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
  const cityName = place.city.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
  const stateName = place.state.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);

    return `
      <li>
        <span class="name">${cityName}, ${stateName}</span>
        <span class="population">${numberWithCommas(place.population)}      </span>
      </li>
    `;

  }).join(''); 
  suggestions.innerHTML = html; 

   // this only works on the second click:
  const searchResult = document.querySelectorAll('li'); 
  searchResult.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
      console.log('hi'); 

  })})


const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches); // change only fires once user navigates away from input field!
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches);

}
```

Comment: The second click on what? Notice that you don't install a click listener before `displayMatches` is executed

Comment: The html elements I want the listener on is generated in `displayMatches`. That's why I've included it in this funtion, at the bottom. Is that the wrong place?

Comment: Nah, that should be fine. I just meant that if `suggestions` did have any content on page load, that would not get any click listeners attached to it, since it was not generated by `displayMatches`.

Comment: So you are saying that when you debug the code, the `el.addEventListener` is executed, but then when clicking on the list items afterwards, no log appears in the console?

Comment: If I console log `el` (or anything else for that matter), nothing happens during the first click. The second click is logged, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: The issue comes from the search input having focus, so the click on the suggestion will `blur` the input and then for some reason ignore the click event on the list item (see related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335325/blur-event-stops-click-event-from-working)). In your case using `mousedown` instead of `click` seems to fix the issue, see updated snippet below.

```js
const cities = [];

// fetch(endpoint)
//  .then(blob => blob.json())
//  .then(data =>cities.push(...data));

// mocking fetch here
_fetch = () => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   resolve([
    {city: 'Los Angeles', state: 'CA', population: '4M'},
    {city: 'New York City', state: 'NY', population: '8.4M'},
    {city: 'Atlanta', state: 'GA', population: '0.5M'},
   ]);
  }, 1000);
 });
};

_fetch()
 .then(data => cities.push(...data));

function findMatches(wordToMatch, cities) {
 return cities.filter(place => {
  const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi'); 
  return place.city.match(regex) || place.state.match(regex);
 });
}

function displayMatches() {
 const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, cities);
 
 const html = matchArray.map(place => {
  const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
  const cityName = place.city.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
  const stateName = place.state.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
  
  return `
   <li>
    <span class="name">${cityName}, ${stateName}</span>
    <span class="population">${place.population}</span>
   </li>
  `;
  
 }).join('');
 
 suggestions.innerHTML = html; 
 
 // this only works on the second click:
 const searchResult = document.querySelectorAll('li'); 
 searchResult.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
   console.log(`Say hi to ${e.currentTarget.innerText}`);
  });
 });
}

const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');
// change only fires once user navigates away from input field!
searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches);
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search" />
<ul class="suggestions">

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried that but it still won't work with my code. Could this somehow be related to the fetch API as the problem only occurs upon page reload? When I run your code snippet, it all works fine!

Comment: @ClaudSliv could reproduce it when adding the search input, the issue seems to be a conflict beteween the blur and click event, see updated snippet above for a solution!

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Using mousedown (though not ideal) fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes I know =/, less than optimal, but couldn't find a better solution myself, the SO post linked above has different approaches, but all have downsides or are overly complicated, therefore I just went for that "simple" fix here, but if you run into issues with keyboard etc. you might need to look for a better solution!